# How can i change the image URL's text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url, replace

I'm using this line to change a specific word in a text to other word:

```
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/katt/g, "smurf");
```

Now I'm trying to use the same line to change an image URL in HTML but it doesn't work. I trying this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/"https://oldimage.jpg"/g, "https://newimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape `//` inside Regex like `\/\/`. You also should not have surrounding `""`:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "https://oldimage.jpg"
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/https:\/\/oldimage.jpg/g, "https://newimage.jpg");
```